# How to traverse XPath recursively?

Tags: java, xpath, abstract-syntax-tree

is there a way (and if so, how ?) to traverse a XPath query recursively ?

I have an AST in Java with the following scenario

```
@Relevant
public void foo() {
   bar(true);
}

public void bar(boolean flag) {
  assert flag;
}
```

I want to find the method which is annotated with '@Relevant' (thats easy) and check if the method which is called in foo (here bar) does have an assert Statement.

So a) how do I extract the methode name 'bar' and ask via XPath for the method called 'bar' ?

and what if 'bar' actually calls 'bla' in which the assert happens ?

hope this is understandable...

Thanks for any help

Comment: It's not clear what is your AST format. I assume that you create its XML configuration. If that is correct provide more details about method call and assert statements definition you use.

I can say that I played with javac sources (available from OpenJDK project) and they build AST programmatically (at the JCTree.JCCompilationUnit format - http://xref.jsecurity.net/openjdk-6/langtools/dd/d25/classcom_1_1sun_1_1tools_1_1javac_1_1tree_1_1_j_c_tree_1_1_j_c_compilation_unit.html). It's easy to accomplish your task via that API then using JCTree.JCCompilationUnit.accept (Visitor).

Comment: the purpose for that is actually creating an XPath rule for PMD.

Due to circumstances I cant use a Java implementation for that.

so either it is possible in XPath or I have to forget the whole idea ;-)

Thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

A single Xpath is not sufficient for the task you're trying to accomplish.

First, you need a type binding (for finding a bar() method declaration, for example).

Second, you need to develop some kind of static code analyzer, which runs on ASTs recursively and tries to satisfy a condition, which is "an assert expression exists" in a call stack.

You may have a look at the Eclipse JDT source code for how type binding is implemented there. Once you have a binding, you can invoke your logic on it.